# Representing and solving a maze given an image

Tags: python, algorithm, matlab, image-processing, maze

What is the best way to represent and solve a maze given an image?

[image: The cover image of The Scope Issue 134]

Given an JPEG image (as seen above), what's the best way to read it in, parse it into some data structure and solve the maze? My first instinct is to read the image in pixel by pixel and store it in a list (array) of boolean values: `True` for a white pixel, and `False` for a non-white pixel (the colours can be discarded). The issue with this method, is that the image may not be "pixel perfect". By that I simply mean that if there is a white pixel somewhere on a wall it may create an unintended path.

Another method (which came to me after a bit of thought) is to convert the image to an SVG file - which is a list of paths drawn on a canvas. This way, the paths could be read into the same sort of list (boolean values) where `True` indicates a path or wall, `False` indicating a travel-able space. An issue with this method arises if the conversion is not 100% accurate, and does not fully connect all of the walls, creating gaps.

Also an issue with converting to SVG is that the lines are not "perfectly" straight. This results in the paths being cubic bezier curves. With a list (array) of boolean values indexed by integers, the curves would not transfer easily, and all the points that line on the curve would have to be calculated, but won't exactly match to list indices.

I assume that while one of these methods may work (though probably not) that they are woefully inefficient given such a large image, and that there exists a better way. How is this best (most efficiently and/or with the least complexity) done? Is there even a best way?

Then comes the solving of the maze. If I use either of the first two methods, I will essentially end up with a matrix. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3097677/1267663), a good way to represent a maze is using a tree, and a good way to solve it is using the [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm). How would one create a tree from the image? Any ideas?

**TL;DR**
Best way to parse? Into what data structure? How would said structure help/hinder solving?

**UPDATE**
I've tried my hand at implementing what @Mikhail has written in Python, using `numpy`, as @Thomas recommended. I feel that the algorithm is correct, but it's not working as hoped. (Code below.) The PNG library is [PyPNG](https://raw.github.com/drj11/pypng/master/code/png.py).

```
import png, numpy, Queue, operator, itertools

def is_white(coord, image):
  """ Returns whether (x, y) is approx. a white pixel."""
  a = True
  for i in xrange(3):
    if not a: break
    a = image[coord[1]][coord[0] * 3 + i] > 240
  return a

def bfs(s, e, i, visited):
  """ Perform a breadth-first search. """
  frontier = Queue.Queue()
  while s != e:
    for d in [(-1, 0), (0, -1), (1, 0), (0, 1)]:
      np = tuple(map(operator.add, s, d))
      if is_white(np, i) and np not in visited:
        frontier.put(np)
    visited.append(s)
    s = frontier.get()
  return visited

def main():
  r = png.Reader(filename = "thescope-134.png")
  rows, cols, pixels, meta = r.asDirect()
  assert meta['planes'] == 3 # ensure the file is RGB
  image2d = numpy.vstack(itertools.imap(numpy.uint8, pixels))
  start, end = (402, 985), (398, 27)
  print bfs(start, end, image2d, [])
```

Comment: I'd convert the maze to black and white and use a path finding cellular automata method to solve it.

Comment: Do you need to deal only with that image, or with many images like that? I.e. is there an option of some manual processing specific for this certain image?

Comment: @Mikhail Just this image, manual processing is an option.

Comment: @Whymarrh I don't code python, but I'm pretty sure you should move `visited.append(s)` under a `for.if` and replace it with `visited.append(np)`. A vertex is visited once it is added to the queue. In fact, this array should be named "queued". You also can terminate BFS once you've reached the finish.

Comment: @Whymarrh And you also seem to have skipped implementing the path extracting block. Without it, you can only find out whether the finish is reachable or not, but not how.

Comment: Not quite sure how it could be implemented but for manual maze cheating one _simply_ has to convert the maze to true b&w and keep *bucket filling* wall segments (with distinct colors for adjacent "islands") and look for "rivers" between them. One should lead from start to finish. OP's sample maze won't resolve to just two islands, but many simpler mazes often do. Even if it might not be feasible as a stand-alone solution it cool be used as an heuristic for path finding: paths for which both the left and right wall are of the same color are dead ends and thus should not be followed any further.

Comment: To find out if there *is* a solution, a UnionFind and a Linear Scan is the fastest algorithm. It doesn't give you the path, but gives you a set of tiles which will have the path as a subset.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

Here is a solution.

1. Convert image to grayscale (not yet binary), adjusting weights for the colors so that final grayscale image is approximately uniform. You can do it simply by controlling sliders in Photoshop in Image -> Adjustments -> Black & White.
2. Convert image to binary by setting appropriate threshold in Photoshop in Image -> Adjustments -> Threshold.
3. Make sure threshold is selected right. Use the Magic Wand Tool with 0 tolerance, point sample, contiguous, no anti-aliasing. Check that edges at which selection breaks are not false edges introduced by wrong threshold. In fact, all interior points of this maze are accessible from the start.
4. Add artificial borders on the maze to make sure virtual traveler will not walk around it :)
5. Implement [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (BFS) in your favorite language and run it from the start. I prefer [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) for this task. As @Thomas already mentioned, there is no need to mess with regular representation of graphs. You can work with binarized image directly.

Here is the MATLAB code for BFS:

```matlab
function path = solve_maze(img_file)
  %% Init data
  img = imread(img_file);
  img = rgb2gray(img);
  maze = img > 0;
  start = [985 398];
  finish = [26 399];

  %% Init BFS
  n = numel(maze);
  Q = zeros(n, 2);
  M = zeros([size(maze) 2]);
  front = 0;
  back = 1;

  function push(p, d)
    q = p + d;
    if maze(q(1), q(2)) && M(q(1), q(2), 1) == 0
      front = front + 1;
      Q(front, :) = q;
      M(q(1), q(2), :) = reshape(p, [1 1 2]);
    end
  end

  push(start, [0 0]);

  d = [0 1; 0 -1; 1 0; -1 0];

  %% Run BFS
  while back <= front
    p = Q(back, :);
    back = back + 1;
    for i = 1:4
      push(p, d(i, :));
    end
  end

  %% Extracting path
  path = finish;
  while true
    q = path(end, :);
    p = reshape(M(q(1), q(2), :), 1, 2);
    path(end + 1, :) = p;
    if isequal(p, start) 
      break;
    end
  end
end
```

It is really very simple and standard, there should not be difficulties on implementing this in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) or whatever.

And here is the answer:

[image]

Comment: @Whymarrh Well, for "Just this image" you now actually have an answer. Do you have any specific questions? Items 1-4 from my list are the manual processing I was asking about. Item 5 is a BFS - the very basic algorithm for graphs, but it can be applied to image directly, without converting pixels to vertices and neighbors to edges.

Comment: I feel that you've covered everything. I'm trying my hand at implementing what you've said in Python (using DFS in place of BFS, only because I've coded that once before). I'll be back to update the question/accept answers in a bit.

Comment: @Whymarrh DFS will not find you the shortest way, while BFS will. They are inherently the same, the only difference is the underlying structure. Stack (FILO) for DFS and queue (FIFO) for BFS.

Comment: I've updated the question to include code, changed from DFS to BFS. I mustn't have written it properly.

Comment: @Whymarrh do you need the shortest path ? If not DFS will probably be much faster. I ask because you don't mention it in the original question.

Comment: @Pavan not the shortest path in particular, any path will do.

Comment: @Pavan I don't agree DFS will be faster than BFS, since, as I've mentioned, their only difference is in underlying data structure. You can terminate both when the finish is reached. And it depends on a maze, who will reach the finish faster.

Comment: BFS is the right choice here, because it produces a shortest path, which gives a "sensible" path even when the corridors are much wider than 1 pixel.  OTOH DFS will tend to explore corridors and unpromising maze regions with a "flood fill" pattern.

Comment: @j_random_hacker That makes more sense now. I was not thinking of corridor width > 1pixel.

Comment: Can you post the unpathed version of the image. I am trying to duplicate your results, but my image has many isolated areas of the maze.

Comment: @JosephKern Path doesn't overlap any walls. Just remove all the red pixels and here you go.

Answer (score 167):

This solution is written in Python. Thanks Mikhail for the pointers on the image preparation.

**An animated Breadth-First Search:**

[image: Animated version of BFS]

**The Completed Maze:**

[image: Completed Maze]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

from Queue import Queue
from PIL import Image

start = (400,984)
end = (398,25)

def iswhite(value):
    if value == (255,255,255):
        return True

def getadjacent(n):
    x,y = n
    return [(x-1,y),(x,y-1),(x+1,y),(x,y+1)]

def BFS(start, end, pixels):

    queue = Queue()
    queue.put([start]) # Wrapping the start tuple in a list

    while not queue.empty():

        path = queue.get() 
        pixel = path[-1]

        if pixel == end:
            return path

        for adjacent in getadjacent(pixel):
            x,y = adjacent
            if iswhite(pixels[x,y]):
                pixels[x,y] = (127,127,127) # see note
                new_path = list(path)
                new_path.append(adjacent)
                queue.put(new_path)

    print "Queue has been exhausted. No answer was found."


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # invoke: python mazesolver.py <mazefile> <outputfile>[.jpg|.png|etc.]
    base_img = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
    base_pixels = base_img.load()

    path = BFS(start, end, base_pixels)

    path_img = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
    path_pixels = path_img.load()

    for position in path:
        x,y = position
        path_pixels[x,y] = (255,0,0) # red

    path_img.save(sys.argv[2])
```

**Note:** Marks a white visited pixel grey. This removes the need for a visited list, but this requires a second load of the image file from disk before drawing a path (if you don't want a composite image of the final path and ALL paths taken).

[A blank version of the maze I used.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmjsB.jpg)

Comment: Because you were awesome enough to come back and upvote me even after your question had been answered, I created an animated gif of the BFS, to help better visualize the process.

Comment: Nice one, thanks. For others who wish to play around with this, as I did, I'd like to share my tips based on difficulties I faced. 1) Either convert the image to pure black & white or modify your 'isWhite()' function to accept near-white|black. I wrote a 'cleanImage' method which preprocessed all pixels converting them to either pure white or black, otherwise the algorithm fails to find a path. 2) Read the image in explicitly as RGB [ base_img = Image.open(img_in); base_img = base_img.convert('RGB') ]. To get a gif,  output several images and then run 'convert -delay 5 -loop 1 *.jpg bfs.gif'.

Answer (score 86):

I tried myself implementing A-Star search for this problem. Followed closely the implementation by [Joseph Kern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13174351/1025391) for the framework and the algorithm pseudocode given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-star#Pseudocode):

```python
def AStar(start, goal, neighbor_nodes, distance, cost_estimate):
    def reconstruct_path(came_from, current_node):
        path = []
        while current_node is not None:
            path.append(current_node)
            current_node = came_from[current_node]
        return list(reversed(path))

    g_score = {start: 0}
    f_score = {start: g_score[start] + cost_estimate(start, goal)}
    openset = {start}
    closedset = set()
    came_from = {start: None}

    while openset:
        current = min(openset, key=lambda x: f_score[x])
        if current == goal:
            return reconstruct_path(came_from, goal)
        openset.remove(current)
        closedset.add(current)
        for neighbor in neighbor_nodes(current):
            if neighbor in closedset:
                continue
            if neighbor not in openset:
                openset.add(neighbor)
            tentative_g_score = g_score[current] + distance(current, neighbor)
            if tentative_g_score >= g_score.get(neighbor, float('inf')):
                continue
            came_from[neighbor] = current
            g_score[neighbor] = tentative_g_score
            f_score[neighbor] = tentative_g_score + cost_estimate(neighbor, goal)
    return []
```

As A-Star is a heuristic search algorithm you need to come up with a function that estimates the remaining cost (here: distance) until the goal is reached. Unless you're comfortable with a suboptimal solution it should not overestimate the cost. A conservative choice would here be the [manhattan (or taxicab) distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) as this represents the straight-line distance between two points on the grid for the used Von Neumann neighborhood. (Which, in this case, wouldn't ever overestimate the cost.)

This would however significantly underestimate the actual cost for the given maze at hand. Therefore I've added two other distance metrics squared euclidean distance and the manhattan distance multiplied by four for comparison. These however might overestimate the actual cost, and might therefore yield suboptimal results.

Here's the code:

```
import sys
from PIL import Image

def is_blocked(p):
    x,y = p
    pixel = path_pixels[x,y]
    if any(c < 225 for c in pixel):
        return True
def von_neumann_neighbors(p):
    x, y = p
    neighbors = [(x-1, y), (x, y-1), (x+1, y), (x, y+1)]
    return [p for p in neighbors if not is_blocked(p)]
def manhattan(p1, p2):
    return abs(p1[0]-p2[0]) + abs(p1[1]-p2[1])
def squared_euclidean(p1, p2):
    return (p1[0]-p2[0])**2 + (p1[1]-p2[1])**2

start = (400, 984)
goal = (398, 25)

# invoke: python mazesolver.py <mazefile> <outputfile>[.jpg|.png|etc.]

path_img = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
path_pixels = path_img.load()

distance = manhattan
heuristic = manhattan

path = AStar(start, goal, von_neumann_neighbors, distance, heuristic)

for position in path:
    x,y = position
    path_pixels[x,y] = (255,0,0) # red

path_img.save(sys.argv[2])
```

Here are some images for a visualization of the results (inspired by the one posted by [Joseph Kern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13174351/1025391)). The animations show a new frame each after 10000 iterations of the main while-loop.

Breadth-First Search:

[image: Breadth-First Search]

A-Star Manhattan Distance:

[image: A-Star Manhattan Distance]

A-Star Squared Euclidean Distance:

[image: A-Star Squared Euclidean Distance]

A-Star Manhattan Distance multiplied by four:

[image: A-Star Manhattan Distance multiplied by four]

The results show that the explored regions of the maze differ considerably for the heuristics being used. As such, squared euclidean distance even produces a different (suboptimal) path as the other metrics.

Concerning the performance of the A-Star algorithm in terms of the runtime until termination, note that a lot of evaluation of distance and cost functions add up compared to the Breadth-First Search (BFS) which only needs to evaluate the "goaliness" of each candidate position. Whether or not the cost for these additional function evaluations (A-Star) outweighs the cost for the larger number of nodes to check (BFS) and especially whether or not performance is an issue for your application at all, is a matter of individual perception and can of course not be generally answered.

A thing that *can* be said in general about whether or not an informed search algorithm (such as A-Star) could be the better choice compared to an exhaustive search (e.g., BFS) is the following. With the number of dimensions of the maze, i.e., the branching factor of the search tree, the disadvantage of an exhaustive search (to search exhaustively) grows exponentially. With growing complexity it becomes less and less feasible to do so and at some point you are pretty much happy with *any* result path, be it (approximately) optimal or not.

Comment: "A-Star Manhattan Distance multiplied by four"? A-Star is not A-Star if the heuristic can overestimate the distance. (And thus does not guarantee to find a shortest path either)

Answer (score 41):

Tree search is too much. The maze is inherently separable along the solution path(s).

(Thanks to [rainman002](http://www.reddit.com/r/coding/comments/11yvxu/solving_a_maze_given_an_image_stack_overflow/c6qtnrr) from Reddit for pointing this out to me.)

Because of this, you can quickly use [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_Component_Labeling) to identify the connected sections of maze wall. This iterates over the pixels twice.

If you want to turn that into a nice diagram of the solution path(s), you can then use binary operations with structuring elements to fill in the "dead end" pathways for each connected region.

Demo code for MATLAB follows. It could use tweaking to clean up the result better, make it more generalizable, and make it run faster. (Sometime when it's not 2:30 AM.)

```
% read in and invert the image
im = 255 - imread('maze.jpg');

% sharpen it to address small fuzzy channels
% threshold to binary 15%
% run connected components
result = bwlabel(im2bw(imfilter(im,fspecial('unsharp')),0.15));

% purge small components (e.g. letters)
for i = 1:max(reshape(result,1,1002*800))
    [count,~] = size(find(result==i));
    if count < 500
        result(result==i) = 0;
    end
end

% close dead-end channels
closed = zeros(1002,800);
for i = 1:max(reshape(result,1,1002*800))
    k = zeros(1002,800);
    k(result==i) = 1; k = imclose(k,strel('square',8));
    closed(k==1) = i;
end

% do output
out = 255 - im;
for x = 1:1002
    for y = 1:800
        if closed(x,y) == 0
            out(x,y,:) = 0;
        end
    end
end
imshow(out);
```

[image: result of current code]

Answer (score 25):

Here you go: [maze-solver-python](https://github.com/scharissis/maze-solver-python) (GitHub)

[image]

I had fun playing around with this and extended on [Joseph Kern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13174351/1505651)'s answer. Not to detract from it; I just made some minor additions for anyone else who may be interested in playing around with this.

It's a python-based solver which uses BFS to find the shortest path. My main additions, at the time, are:

1. The image is cleaned before the search (ie. convert to pure black & white)
2. Automatically generate a GIF.
3. Automatically generate an AVI.

As it stands, the start/end-points are hard-coded for this sample maze, but I plan on extending it such that you can pick the appropriate pixels.

Comment: Great, thanks, it did not run on BSD/Darwin/Mac, some dependencies and the shell script needed minor changes, for those who want to try on Mac:
[maze-solver-python]: https://github.com/holg/maze-solver-python

Comment: @HolgT: Glad you found it useful. I welcome any pull requests for this. :)

Answer (score 24):

Uses a queue for a threshold continuous fill. Pushes the pixel left of the entrance onto the queue and then starts the loop. If a queued pixel is dark enough, it's colored light gray (above threshold), and all the neighbors are pushed onto the queue.

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("/tmp/in.jpg")
(w,h) = img.size
scan = [(394,23)]
while(len(scan) > 0):
    (i,j) = scan.pop()
    (r,g,b) = img.getpixel((i,j))
    if(r*g*b < 9000000):
        img.putpixel((i,j),(210,210,210))
        for x in [i-1,i,i+1]:
            for y in [j-1,j,j+1]:
                scan.append((x,y))
img.save("/tmp/out.png")
```

Solution is the corridor between gray wall and colored wall. Note this maze has multiple solutions. Also, this merely appears to work.

[image: Solution]

Comment: Interesting naive resolution, based on the hand-on-wall method. Indeed, not the best one, but I like it.

Answer (score 5):

I'd go for the matrix-of-bools option. If you find that standard Python lists are too inefficient for this, you could use a `numpy.bool` array instead. Storage for a 1000x1000 pixel maze is then just 1 MB.

Don't bother with creating any tree or graph data structures. That's just a way of thinking about it, but not necessarily a good way to represent it in memory; a boolean matrix is both easier to code and more efficient.

Then use the A* algorithm to solve it. For the distance heuristic, use the Manhattan distance (`distance_x + distance_y`).

Represent nodes by a tuple of `(row, column)` coordinates. Whenever the algorithm ([Wikipedia pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm#Pseudocode)) calls for "neighbours", it's a simple matter of looping over the four possible neighbours (mind the edges of the image!).

If you find that it's still too slow, you could try downscaling the image before you load it. Be careful not to lose any narrow paths in the process.

Maybe it's possible to do a 1:2 downscaling in Python as well, checking that you don't actually lose any possible paths. An interesting option, but it needs a bit more thought.

Comment: [This excellent blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2010/11/03/amazeing-image-processing-in-mathematica/) shows how to solve a maze in mathematica. Translating the method to python shouldn't be a problem

Comment: I've updated the question. If I choose to use RGB triples in lieu of `boolean` values, would the storage still compare? The matrix is then 2400 * 1200. And would A* over BFS have a significant impact on real running time?

Comment: @Whymarrh, the bit depth can shrink to compensate.  2 bits per pixel should be enough for anybody.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some ideas.

(1. Image Processing:)

1.1 Load the image as [RGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) pixel map. In [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) it is trivial using `system.drawing.bitmap`. In languages with no simple support for imaging, just convert the image to  [portable pixmap format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) (PPM) (a Unix text representation, produces large files) or some simple binary file format you can easily read, such as [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) or [TGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truevision_TGA). [ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) in Unix or [IrfanView](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IrfanView) in Windows.

1.2 You may, as mentioned earlier, simplify the data by taking the (R+G+B)/3 for each pixel as an indicator of gray tone and then threshold the value to produce a black and white table. Something close to 200 assuming 0=black and 255=white will take out the JPEG artifacts.

(2. Solutions:)

2.1 Depth-First Search: Init an empty stack with starting location, collect available follow-up moves, pick one at random and push onto the stack, proceed until end is reached or a deadend. On deadend backtrack by popping the stack, you need to keep track of which positions were visited on the map so when you collect available moves you never take the same path twice. Very interesting to animate.

2.2 Breadth-First Search: Mentioned before, similar as above but only using queues. Also interesting to animate. This works like flood-fill in image editing software. I think you may be able to solve a maze in Photoshop using this trick.

2.3 Wall Follower: Geometrically speaking, a maze is a folded/convoluted tube. If you keep your hand on the wall you will eventually find the exit ;) This does not always work. There are certain assumption re: perfect mazes, etc., for instance, certain mazes contain islands. Do look it up; it is fascinating.

(3. Comments:)

This is the tricky one. It is easy to solve mazes if represented in some simple array formal with each element being a cell type with north, east, south and west walls and a visited flag field. However given that you are trying to do this given a hand drawn sketch it becomes messy. I honestly think that trying to rationalize the sketch will drive you nuts. This is akin to computer vision problems which are fairly involved. Perhaps going directly onto the image map may be easier yet more wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using R.

```
### download the image, read it into R, converting to something we can play with...
library(jpeg)
url <- "https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqKCM.jpg"
download.file(url, "./maze.jpg", mode = "wb")
jpg <- readJPEG("./maze.jpg")

### reshape array into data.frame
library(reshape2)
img3 <- melt(jpg, varnames = c("y","x","rgb"))
img3$rgb <- as.character(factor(img3$rgb, levels = c(1,2,3), labels=c("r","g","b")))

## split out rgb values into separate columns
img3 <- dcast(img3, x + y ~ rgb)
```

RGB to greyscale, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27491947/2371031

```
# convert rgb to greyscale (0, 1)
img3$v <- img3$r*.21 + img3$g*.72 + img3$b*.07
# v: values closer to 1 are white, closer to 0 are black

## strategically fill in some border pixels so the solver doesn't "go around":
img3$v2 <- img3$v
img3[(img3$x == 300 | img3$x == 500) & (img3$y %in% c(0:23,988:1002)),"v2"]  = 0

# define some start/end point coordinates
pts_df <- data.frame(x = c(398, 399),
                     y = c(985, 26))

# set a reference value as the mean of the start and end point greyscale "v"s
ref_val <- mean(c(subset(img3, x==pts_df[1,1] & y==pts_df[1,2])$v,
                  subset(img3, x==pts_df[2,1] & y==pts_df[2,2])$v))

library(sp)
library(gdistance)
spdf3 <- SpatialPixelsDataFrame(points = img3[c("x","y")], data = img3["v2"])
r3 <- rasterFromXYZ(spdf3)

# transition layer defines a "conductance" function between any two points, and the number of connections (4 = Manhatten distances)
# x in the function represents the greyscale values ("v2") of two adjacent points (pixels), i.e., = (x1$v2, x2$v2)
# make function(x) encourages transitions between cells with small changes in greyscale compared to the reference values, such that: 
# when v2 is closer to 0 (black) = poor conductance
# when v2 is closer to 1 (white) = good conductance
tl3 <- transition(r3, function(x) (1/max( abs( (x/ref_val)-1 ) )^2)-1, 4) 

## get the shortest path between start, end points
sPath3 <- shortestPath(tl3, as.numeric(pts_df[1,]), as.numeric(pts_df[2,]), output = "SpatialLines")

## fortify for ggplot
sldf3 <- fortify(SpatialLinesDataFrame(sPath3, data = data.frame(ID = 1)))

# plot the image greyscale with start/end points (red) and shortest path (green)
ggplot(img3) +
  geom_raster(aes(x, y, fill=v2)) +
  scale_fill_continuous(high="white", low="black") +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  geom_point(data=pts_df, aes(x, y), color="red") +
  geom_path(data=sldf3, aes(x=long, y=lat), color="green")
```

Voila!

[image: solution that correctly finds shortest path]

This is what happens if you don't fill in some border pixels (Ha!)...

[image: solution version where the solver goes around the maze]

Full disclosure: I asked and answered a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52601127/2371031) myself before I found this one.  Then through the magic of SO, found this one as one of the top "Related Questions".  I thought I'd use this maze as an additional test case... I was very pleased to find that my answer there also works for this application with very little modification.

Answer (score 0):

the good solution would be that instead of finding the neighbors by pixel, it would be done by cell, because a corridor can have 15px so in the same corridor it can take actions like left or right, while if it was done as if the displacement was a cube it would be a simple action like UP,DOWN,LEFT OR RIGHT

Comment: Can you add the solution graph and algorithm like the rest of the answer to validate your point? It will be better if you can add those to add more weightage to your answer so that others can actually get more understanding of your answer.