# Working out and visualizing possible destinations given location and movement distance

Tags: c#, math, trigonometry, 2d-games

I am currently developing a game in unity and I was wondering how to solve the following problem.

I have a character on a 2d map which can move up to x meters distance per turn. I want to be able to be able to display the area he can possibly move into on the 2d map.

This is simple to solve if the map is empty, I simply draw a circle around the character with the radius being x. The problem becomes more tricky if there are obstacles in the way, for instance there might be a tree or hill that the character cannot traverse through. I need to be able to calculate the max distance around the obstacles as well.

Initially I was thinking of using a flood fill algorithm (DFS) to calculate the possible places the character could be but this seems prone to inaccuracy if I use too coarse spacing between points and would be computationally expensive if too fine. The obstacle collision areas are represented as a 2d polygon stored as an array of 2d Vector points. I am currently visualizing these on the screen as a red lined 2d polygon. I would like to draw an outline around the character that represents the area that he can reach in a turn but the above solution will always criss cross over the red collision outlines.

I was wondering if there are any other possible approaches that I could take or any optimization/modification of the DFS that could work.

Answer (score 0):

1. create 2D map

   - I assume you already have it
   - it should be 2D array (bitmap like)
   - empty space and walls/obstacles should have specific colors
2. use A* algorithm

   - like this [mine A* implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23779490/2521214)
   - start from point/object of interest
   - just do not fill until the end
   - instead stop after N cycles (moves)
   - this will give you map of possible destinations per N-moves
3. visualize back