# 2D drawing c++ for grid maze project

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d

I am building a c++ maze project for school and want to create a 2d graphics window in c++ that will let me render something like this http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/uploads/monthly_07_2011/post-114496-13104660729008.png.

Can anyone suggest a 2d graphics library to use? I have looked into openGL but am worried that the geometry necessary is too complicated for what I need. Of course I may be overlooking some things.

I am working in Xcode on OS X and if the library is not multiplatform that is okay. Can anyone suggest me something?

Comment: Why are all these answers being down voted? The question is bad, because it asks for a tool, but these answers are answering just fine in my opinion.

Comment: I know the question is bad, but in the sense that it is too nonspecific but tailored to one use case. I ask because there is nowhere else on the internet I can receive feedback like this. The answers are down voted because they support this kind of inquiry abuse.

Comment: @user3667450 what is bad with OpenGL ? use GL_QUADS from GL 1.0 and you are fine ... (no need for perspective,textures,zbufer,...). btw I am windows programmer so I would go with GDI for this but on OS X have no clue if you have something similar. Also look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23779490/2521214 it might be of help to your project

Answer (score 2):

The [Qt framework](http://qt-project.org/downloads) is a cross-platform solution for building applications.

There is a [basic drawing example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwidgets-painting-basicdrawing-example.html) that shows how to use basic graphic primitives:

[image]

The core of the technique consists in reimplementing a widget's `paintEvent()` method to control how it is displayed (painted) on the screen. The `QPainter` class provides many drawing methods to suit your needs.

Comment: Old McDonald had a farm, ee i ee i o.

Answer (score 0):

Since cross-platform is not a problem, just use [Quartz](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html) or [SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html). Quartz is general 2D drawing, SpriteKit is specifically for games. All the docs you can access directly in Xcode through the documentation window, and Apple provides a bunch of sample code too.