# Are backtracking algorithms always using recursion?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, backtracking

All backtracking algorithms that I used so far were based on recursion. But I wasn't able to find any evidence that backtracking cannot be non-recursive. So the question is whether backtracking algorithms are always using recursion?

Comment: Every recursive algorithm can be automatically rewritten in a non-recursive one: simply push and pop data that you would have pushed/popped on the call stack on a regular stack.

Comment: Recursion is just a matter of implementation. It lends itself well for backtracking, and that's why you will generally see recursion in those algorithms. However, like @WillemVanOnsem says, there's noone forcing you to implement it using recursion.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking#Description_of_the_method

Comment: iterative version of [grid A* is backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28317199/2521214) without any recursion ... it is simple `O(n)` loop without any stack ...

Answer (score 2):

Nope, backtracking can be done without recursion. Here is an example: [Non-recursive backtracking, using a stack](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ematuszek/cit594-2012/Pages/backtracking.html#:%7E:text=Non%2Drecursive%20backtracking%2C%20using%20a%20stack&text=Nodes%20are%20removed%20from%20the,no%20solution%20to%20the%20problem.):

```
boolean solve(Node n) {
    put node n on the stack;
    while the stack is not empty {
        if the node at the top of the stack is a leaf {
            if it is a goal node, return true
            else pop it off the stack
        }
        else {
            if the node at the top of the stack has untried children
                push the next untried child onto the stack
            else pop the node off the stack

    }
    return false
}
```

### A real example

[The N-Queens Problem](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/recursion/recursion-and-backtracking/tutorial/)

- [recursive solution](https://github.com/tylerlong/hackerearth/blob/main/practice/basic-programming/recursion/recursion-and-backtracking/tutorial/index.py)
- [non-recursive solution](https://github.com/tylerlong/hackerearth/blob/main/practice/basic-programming/recursion/recursion-and-backtracking/tutorial/index2.py)

And as I tested, the non-recursive solution is significantly faster. I am not saying that non-recursive solution is always faster, but it does offer more flexibility for performance optimization(instead of saving the whole call stack, you decide what to put into the stack).